# What is the minimum spatial IQ needed to solve the rubik's cube?

Tags: spatial-cognition

Solving the rubki's cube is bona fide spatial IQ challenge.

Has there been studies done on the minimum spatial IQ score needed to solve it?

EDIT:

By solve, I mean to discover the algorithm by oneself.

Comment: I was wondering this myself and I can't find a solution. I am 42 and I've owned a Rubik's cube since I was 16.  I refuse to look up solution algorithms.  I can solve the top and second layers by steps I've figured out on my own, but there have been just to many steps to recall and process to finish the last level, but I've been close needing to swap only 2x pieces.  I don't fiddle with this a lot but maybe 2-3 times a year, where I'll fiddle with the thing at my desk between tasks, and I'll do this for a week before I give up.  I hope to one day crack it. We'll see.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's a matter of IQ, really. Here's why: The Rubik's cube can be solved easily following a simple algorithm. Anyone can follow this step-by-step process mindlessly and solve a Rubik's cube. Remembering the algorithm is a different thing altogether, maybe that depends on a person's IQ ([does memory depend on IQ?](https://www.google.com/search?q=does%20long%20term%20memory%20depend%20on%20iq&ei=xiuUYI_CNdW1rQG9nbmYBA&oq=does%20long%20term%20memory%20depend%20on%20iq&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAM6BwgAEEcQsAM6BAghEApQm_oBWMaPAmCVkgJoA3ACeACAAc8BiAGJD5IBBjAuMTIuMZgBAKABAaoBB2d3cy13aXrIAQjAAQE&sclient=gws-wiz&ved=0ahUKEwiPve3HzrXwAhXVWisKHb1ODkMQ4dUDCA4&uact=5)) There are many bots that can solve the Rubik's cube in a matter of seconds, just following this algorithm. So, it actually doesn't need much IQ I guess, but considering that the algorithm generally starts from the step after one side (usually black/white/yellow) is completed, a person should have enough IQ to be able to solve one face of the cube and remember the steps, so I am guessing that the IQ measure would be around the room temperature in Celsius scale!

Comment: I appreciate the attempt to answer this question but this isn't the answer.  The question asker (and myself) are curious about what type of intellect it take to naturally figure out steps or algorithms to solve a cube, without assistance from others.  Yes, there are plenty of solutions and some can solve puzzles in remarkably few turns.  But for someone who wants to go in "cold" with no knowledge of cube solutions, what intellect does it take to figure this thing out?  As I commented above, I can get close... but I still can't solve this thing after 24 years (again, without assistance.)